# how to efficiently retreive the latest image in an imagecollection in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm building a function that take 2 parameters, an crop mask image collection (I need to be agnostic) and a crop year int. With this what i want to do is either the filtered image collection contains images and then I take the latest one or alternatively I take the latest one from the unfiltered dataset (i.e. the latest available).

My current implementation relies on the `ee.Algorithm.If`method that is super expensive as I always evaluate both sorted and filtered collection. Is there a more clever way to proceed?

```py
def get_cropyear_mask(ic: ee.ImageCollection, crop_year: Optional[int] = None) -> ee.Image:
    """Get Image corresponding to a specific year or the latest available if not specified.""" 
    
    # get the cropyear as an int and build the start and end dates
    # if crop year is not set we take a wide range of dates that should cover all the images
    int_crop_year = crop_year_int(crop_year)
    start_date = f"{int_crop_year}-01-01" if int_crop_year else "1500-01-01"
    end_date = f"{int_crop_year + 1}-01-01" if int_crop_year else f"{datetime.now().year}-01-01"

    # Filter the image collection for the selected time and sort them from the latest to the oldest
    # then we select the first one. In case the collection is empty we simply retrieve the latest image
    # from the initial collection
    sorted = ic.limit(1, "system:time_start", False)
    filtered = ic.filterDate(start_date, end_date).sort("system:time_start", False)
    latest_image = ee.Algorithms.If(filtered.size().gt(0), filtered.first(), sorted.first())

    # results of algorithms are computedObjects so we force cast it to an Image
    return ee.Image(latest_image)
```

the crop mask can be anything from a public dataset to customized crop masks from my company so I cannot and cannot consistently rely on the catalog to retrieve the latest date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the `If()` by just merging the collections and taking the `first()`.

Comment: isn't it super expensive from a EECU standpoint ?

Comment: It's all lazy evaluation; if there's an image in the first collection, then first() will never touch the second collection, so it (probably) wont be sorted.

Comment: but then the first one will always be the first from sorted right ? In my case I'm satisfying with the latest from the filtered collection if it's not empty even if it's older than the real latest from sorted.

Comment: If the filtered collection is empty, then the first image from the merged collections will be from the second one.

Comment: ok I got it you merge without sorting. Understood, thanks!